# Map Icons to Categories from API Call React Typescript Frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, icons

I have a list of categories coming form an API call:

```
Diagnosis
Client Statements
Damages
```

I need to assign an icon on the frontend to each of the categories received and I thought the best way to do this was to map the categories using a `switch` statement.

```
let icon = '';
const handleIcon = () => {
  categories.map((cat) => {

    switch (cat.categoryName) {
      case 'Diagnosis':
        icon = 'checklist-24';
        break;
      case 'Client Statements':
        icon = 'document-24';
        break;
      case 'Damages':
        icon = 'car-crash-24'
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
};
```

My problem is that all the categories end up being the last icon because they are all true in the end for my map function.

```
categories.map((cat) => {
  <div>{icon}</div>
  <div>{cat.categoryName}</div>
})
```

How can I assign a different icon according to the name of the category in my map?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right way to handle this kind of scenarios, which is, when you have to do extra manipulations on your data before displaying them:

```
const cats = [
  { categoryName: 'Diagnosis' },
  { categoryName: 'Client Statements' },
  { categoryName: 'Damages' },
];

export default function App() {

  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(cats);

  const _categories = useMemo(() => {
    return categories.map((cat) => ({
      ...cat,
      icon: getIcon(cat.categoryName),
    }));
  }, [categories]);

  return (
    <div>
      {_categories.map((cat) => (
        <div>
          {cat.categoryName}:{cat.icon}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function getIcon(name) {
  switch (name) {
    case 'Diagnosis':
      return 'checklist-24';
    case 'Client Statements':
      return 'document-24';
    case 'Damages':
      return 'car-crash-24';
    default:
      return '';
  }
}
```

In this way you are memoizing your manipulation which is anyway expensive and you don't want it to happen on each rerender if categories don't change, and you use a pure function *getIcon()* to attach the relative icon to your category object. You can attach whatever you want, even a JSX Component to be displayed directly.

Test it [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-asb5ou)